# Changing Node Image When Touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am having an issue, i want my node to change texture(image) when tapped, currently it changes the next spawning node texture and not the one that was tapped.

I'm not sure why this is happening, and since i can't see whats wrong i can't  try to fix it.

I've been trying different solutions with no success, i have posted a GIST with all the source code and a youtube video showing the problem.

If anyone.... anyone out there can help me solve this, i can't be thankful enough!

- https://gist.github.com/bertobettencourt/11098116

Sorry for the gist, but it's a lot of code and it would be confusing to paste it here.

Thank you!

Comment: Please include the touch delegate as well in the gist.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is the following in the touchesBegan method:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation]; 
    // Now that we have our touchedNode instance set the texture.
    touchedNode.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"rescued"];
}
```